# Getting error every time I drag-and-drop a piece in my chess board

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, console

I was testing around with the jQuery's drag and drop feature, and I am getting the following error in the JSconsole:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined
```

I am trying to do a board game that you move pieces around, basically, like this:

- The board is a table, empty squares are empty `<td></td>`
- the non-empty TDs have `<div class="..."></div>` inside, the div class is either `drag` or `nodrag` (depending on whose turn is)
- When dragging, what jQuery does is to give position relative and adjust the top/left
- When dropping, what I am doing is to get the old and new squares, and use `appendTo()`, and in the case there is a div, I first `remove()` it
- After a valid drop, I toggle the classes `drag` and `nodrag`, first removing the droppable attribute, then adding this to the new draggable

Here is the two crucial parts of the code (and [here a jsFidle](http://jsfiddle.net/n6kRr/1/)):

```
function toggleDrag(){
    //remove the (old) draggables
    if($(".drag").data("draggable")){//prevent crash when nobody is draggable
        $(".drag").draggable("destroy");
    }

    //swapp classes
    var tmp=$(".drag");
    var tmp2=$(".nodrag");
    tmp.removeClass("drag").addClass("nodrag");
    tmp2.removeClass("nodrag").addClass("drag");

    //make the (new) draggables
    $(".drag").draggable({
        revert:"invalid"
    });
}
```

and inside every square (`<td>`):

```
$("td").droppable({
    drop:function(ev,ui){
        var tar=$(this);
        var xdiv=$("#"+tar.attr("id")+" div");

        //if the square is not empty
        if(xdiv.length){
            xdiv.remove();//remove piece
        }

        //I removed styles to reset Top/Left to 0
        //append_TO_ moves the div
        ui.draggable.removeAttr("style").appendTo(tar);

        //I call the toggler funcion
        toggleDrag();
    }
});
```

**Note:** I am well aware that if you drop the piece in the same square that it was dragged, really bad things happen, in my full code I sanitize the droppables to only allow legal moves

Any ideas why this perfectly working code is triggering this console error?

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing this error because destroying the draggable element *inside* the `drop` handler (apparently) isn't allowed.

One hacky way to work around this is to replace

```
toggleDrag();
```

inside your `drop` handler with

```
setTimeout(toggleDrag, 0);
```

Comment: I am sorry to unaccept, but I found a better solution which not only look less hacky, but it also prevents the error when a piece is slowly returning after an invalid placement and quickly moving before it returned (and your timeout didn't solve this part).

Answer (score 0):

After some more testing, I concluded that the `stop:` of draggables are triggered *after* the `drop:` of droppables, so I just moved `toggleDrag()` to here:

```
$(".drag").draggable({
    //... ,
    stop:function(ev,ui){
        toggleDrag(); //a check is needed to make sure it was dropped on dropables though
    }
});
```

The old problem was also triggered if you dropped a piece outside the board (and while it was slowly returning) and you quickly move other piece. This fixes this too.